# Perpendicular Distance Markers on Polyline in MapInfo?

Tags: distance, mapinfo, line, linear-referencing

I have added chainage to a creek polyline in MapInfo v11.0.3 using the 1999 version of "Distance Marker" by Meridian.

It looks poor as it does not have the functionality to create the markers perpendicular to the winding creek.

Any other tools I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MapInfo Pro you also get free access to the tool MapCAD. MapCAD has a feature called "Continouos Dimension Line".

This will let you draw a polyline from a start point via any number of points you want to measure to and to a end point.

MapCAD will now draw a line from the start point to the end point and create perpendicular lines to each of the via points. I guess the image below describe it better than I can with a thousand words

[image: The result of the Continouos Dimension Line tool]

The image shows where the tool is integrated into the Ribbon interface of MapInfo Pro 15.2. For MapInfo Pro 11.0 you will find the tool on the MapCAD buttonpad. You might have to launch the tool from the Tool Manager as it isn't autoloaded by default.